# wpf insert data from views using mvvm method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am new in wpf .i want to know how to insert data from views to XML using mvvm method. i am using xml as database.actually i want to know how data go to view model when press save button.

Comment: What are your views? What data? Show some code

Comment: i ant the full step to insert data using mvvm method

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use `XmlDocument` type to load the Xml data and then bind it to `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` property. Create columns based on `xmlNode.Attributes`.

Answer (score 1):

In `MVVM` your current/present data always exist in `ViewModel`, so there is no need to pass data to `View Model` in order to save it. Your `View` always shows/display data that exist in `ViewModel`. So on `Save` button click you should just save data in to `XML` which already exist in `ViewModel` most probably contained in some collection or other similar data structure.